# Is (1 - Coherence) a metric, at a given frequency?

Tags: time-series, self-study, signal-processing, metric, spectral-analysis

I'm performing some signal analysis and was using coherence (magnitude-squared coherence) to inference signals similarity. Now, I need to extend the framework by introducing a metric. 
I was wondering, whether $1-Coherence(f)$ is a proper metric at a given frequency $f$, considering the fact that coherence is a Fourier transform of cross-correlation function, for which both $1-corr$ and $1-corr^2$ violates triangular inequality, thus both are not a metric.

It would be awesome if anyone can provide not just a simple 'yes-no' answer but also explain (or at least provide hints for the proof) why, or why not, $1-Coherence(f)$ is a metric.

There was a similar [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229253/is-spectral-coherence-a-metric) asked almost two years ago, but no answer was provided.

Comment: I think you should include the self study tag.

Answer (score 0):

I want to pinpoint some restrictions of the function coherence(f) before reaching the conclusion. If you are eager to establish a model based on metrics to solve maybe a real-life problem, it is a great start!

If Coherence(f) is a function which takes value from 0 to 1, i.e., $0 \le Coherence(f) \le 1$ for all the domain defined, then it is indeed a valid metric (of course in some occasion the restriction can be loosen).

Hope it helps. If there are more things needed, feel free to ask and I will try my best.

Comment: I use magnitude-squared coherence, so its values are in the interval between 0 and 1 for the whole domain. However, coherence function of two time series `x,y` is essentially a Fourier transform of the cross-correlation function of two time series, and it's well known that neither `1 - corr(x,y)` nor `1 - corr(x,y)^2` is a metric. In particular, both do not satisfy triangular inequality. So, my concern is whether the same holds true when we switch to the frequency domain?